# TopN, Grouping, Show Others at the bottom POWERBI-DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following formula which creates the table in the screenshot below on the left (names of actual tables are different - also it combines 2 separate tables in one) -

[image]

```
Top 11 Jun =
IF (
   [Type Rank Jun] <= 11,
   [Total Jun],
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( Partners[partner_group] ),
    IF (
        VALUES ( Partners[partner_group] ) = "Others",
        SUMX (
            FILTER ( ALL ( Partners[partner_group] ), [Type Rank Jun] > 11 ),
            [Total Jun]
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Now i'm stuck on how to combine the "Null" and "Others" under "Others" and put "Others" at the bottom.i can combine the "Null" & "Others" at each table level, i'm just not sure how.

Comment: if i can't combine the Null and Others value (as null falls under top 11), how can i bring "Others" to the bottom of the table? thank you

Answer (score 0):

**The DAX solution:**

To get the Other and blank (at least that is how I read your null) together, you can create a new column on the table (is easiest).

```
newProducts = IF(fruits[product] = BLANK(); "Other";fruits[product])
```

**A better solution is to replace your blanks (or NULL) in the Query language:**

Go to: Edit Query:
[image]

Select your table and the product column and press on the bar the "Replace values"

[image]

Do the replace and save and close the editor.

**Last step**

It is not relevant in which order you have the rows in the table because you can control this in the visual self.

Below example:
[image]

As you can see, I filtered other out, this is not needed when you want to count them in your top N.

If you want to show all four, we need to make a new Table:

```
Tabel = 
var Top3 = TOPN(3;FILTER(fruits;fruits[product] <> "Other") ;fruits[July Avail])
var prioTop3 = ADDCOLUMNS(Top3;"Order"; CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(fruits);FILTER(Top3; fruits[July Avail] <= EARLIER(fruits[July Avail]))))
var Other = ADDCOLUMNS(GROUPBY(FILTER(fruits;fruits[product] = "Other");fruits[product];"June Avail"; SUMX(CURRENTGROUP();fruits[June Avail]); "July Avail"; SUMX(CURRENTGROUP();fruits[July Avail]));"Order";0)
return UNION(prioTop3; Other)
```

Result:

[image]